# Problem in hosting Django REST API on IIS

Tags: django, api, iis, django-rest-framework, hosting

I was trying to host django REST API on IIS but it wasn't working properly. I worked with the same locally and it was working absolutely fine.

But when I hosted it on IIS then first of all its homepage with **get** method for all data from the database takes longer time to load and ended up with timeout error. And, when I tried to access other pages, the same problem occurred with them too. Only a page with **post** method opened but when I tried to submit data it raised an error. 
I checked server configuration then I found that default error is timeout error. Now I am confused about why such things happened.

Can anyone please tell me if they faced similar issue or if they know some kind of compatibility issue or some prerequisite for hosting REST API using Django REST Framework? Or help me how can I find and fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please share which database you use with API (SQLite, ms SQL)? how you configure your API with iis? which permission is assigned to the site older and database? under which application pool identity your application pool is running?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FastCGI? check the Authentication then try to disable windows authentication and enable anonymous authentication, try that if it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).